# tableView not scrolling properly inside UIView

Tags: swift, view, uiview, tableview, frame

I have a tableView made programmatic. I initialised the size of the section and the row. I also put a containerView inside the storyboard which would contain the tableView. My problem is, my table view wouldn't scroll properly.

Here would be my storyboard:

[image]

Here would be my outlet for the view in the storyboard:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var trainingDetailsContainerView: UIView!
```

Here would be my initialized table:

```swift
var moduleLessonsTableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
//    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.backgroundColor = Themes.gray_dec
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 35
    tableView.rowHeight = 50
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
    tableView.register(TrainingModulesTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ModuleLessonsCell")

    return tableView
}()
```

And here is where I would set up my tableView, heights and all:

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    moduleLessonsTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: trainingDetailsContainerView.frame.width, height: trainingDetailsContainerView.frame.height)

    trainingDetailsContainerView.addSubview(moduleLessonsTableView)
}
```

I can try putting it in viewWillAppear and the height would render correctly, which had me realizing the bounds of the trainingDetailsContainerView is set before the other views, I think. But the problem with it is it will suddenly pop up. I really don't want that as it looks like a lag from a user's perspective.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I also can't tag view **lifecycles** so I'll just put this here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add constraints to your table view in `viewDidLoad` instead of setting frame. Also remove code from `viewWillAppear` method.
Example code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    trainingDetailsContainerView.addSubview(moduleLessonsTableView)
    moduleLessonsTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trainingDetailsContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    moduleLessonsTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trainingDetailsContainerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    moduleLessonsTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trainingDetailsContainerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    moduleLessonsTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trainingDetailsContainerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: hey, thank you! I'm not sure how but this made a huge difference. Also set it to active = true. Thanlks @Gienadij Mackiewicz

Comment: Your welcome, glad it helped :)
Yeah, forgot about setting `isActive` to true. Answer edited to include missing constraints activation part.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked - this ViewController should work:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var trainingDetailsContainerView: UIView!

    var moduleLessonsTableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.backgroundColor = Themes.gray_dec
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 35
        tableView.rowHeight = 50
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        tableView.register(TrainingModulesTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ModuleLessonsCell")

        return tableView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        trainingDetailsContainerView.addSubview(moduleLessonsTableView)
        moduleLessonsTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trainingDetailsContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        moduleLessonsTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trainingDetailsContainerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        moduleLessonsTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trainingDetailsContainerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        moduleLessonsTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trainingDetailsContainerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: this was what I made, thanks. I also removed setting my row and section header heights at the initializer since there is a delegate for that(?). @Vadim Nikolaev